# Combinatorics. Picking items with and without replacement. Am I reasoning in a right way?

Tags: combinatorics

We have n keys and we want to choose right one to open the door.

a. We choose keys w/o replacement.
What is probability to choose right one: one the first try, second try, k-th try?

b. What if we do it with replacement?

Ok, so when we consider case w/o replacement.

**P(1st try) = 1/n**

**P(2nd try) = (n-1)/n * 1/(n-1)** <- not sure if I am right here. But I think for 2nd try we need to include probability that we did not pick right one on the first try. Correct?

**P(k-th try) = ( (n-k)/n )^k * 1/(n-k)** <- again, not sure if it is correct. But I feel like it should be

b. with replacement (ok, here I am a bit confused)
I think our first probability must be the same

**P(1st try) = 1/n**

**P(2nd try)** ??? I am not sure here. Most probably it is same as P(1st try)?

Meaning, **P(1st try) = P(2nd try) = P(3rd try) + ...+ P(k-th try)?**

From the first glance it seems right, but I believe it is not how it really works..
I will be really thankful for a help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For without replacement, there is a simple solution. Line up the keys in the order you will try them. The "right" key is equally likely to be in any of the $n$ positions. So for $1\le k\le n$, the probability that we use $k$ trials is $\frac{1}{n}$.

For with replacement, on any trial the probability of success is $\frac{1}{n}$, and the probability of failure is $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

So the probability that $k=1$ is $\frac{1}{n}$.

We use $2$ trials if we get failure, then success. The probability of this is $\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$.

We use $3$ trials if we have $2$ consecutive failures, and then success. The probability of this is $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{n}$.

Continue. In the replacement case, the probability it takes exactly $t$ trials is
$\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{t-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$. Here $t$ can be any positive integer.

**Remark:** We can also do the no replacement calculation a harder way. The first success happens on the second trial if we get failure, then success. The probability of failure on the first trial is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. **Given** that we had failure on the first trial, there are $n-1$ keys left, of which $1$ is the right one, so the conditional probability of success on the second trial, given that we had failure on the first, is $\frac{1}{n-1}$. Thus the probability we get the right key on the second trial is $\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n-1}$, which is $\frac{1}{n}$.

For success on the third trial, we must have failure, failure, then success. The associated probability is $\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n-2}$, which again is $\frac{1}{n}$.

We could continue, but it is easier to use the argument in the answer above.

Comment: yes, I was actually thinking this way.. not sure why I considered this wrong. So first solution (a) is correct, right?

Comment: By using an argument like the one you started (please see the Remark at the end of the answer above) we can show that in the no replacement case all the probabilities are $\frac{1}{n}$. You had the second trial one right, but did not simplify. The $k$-th trial one was not right.

Comment: I am surprised how it turns out that probability without replacement equals 1/n for all turns... how it is even possible..

Comment: Hmmm.. I think.. I understand it. All turns are equally likely.
But .. it would be more logically to see for with replacement case.
When we do not replace we make our n smaller.. and if we still did not find one right during our previous turns probability that we will find it later increases...

Comment: I mean if we did not find it all way till nth element, the right one MUST be at n-th place. So probability must be 1. Why it is still 1/n?

Comment: You are mixing up *conditional probability* and probability. Suppose that there are $5$ keys. The probability of **not** finding the right key in the first $4$ trials is $\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$. Multiply out. We get $\frac{1}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

**B)**
$$P(\text{1st try})=\frac{1}{n}$$
$$P(\text{2nd try})=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$
$$P(\text{k:th try})=(\frac{n-1}{n})^{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Thanks.. I also was thinking about it.. but was not sure if it is right :)
So first one is correct, yes?

Comment: btw I did a mistake on my first comment. Look at the k:th try. It should be to the power of $k-1$ not just $k$.

Comment: You are correct on the 1st and 2nd try on **a)**. But when it comes to the k:th try it should be just $\frac{1}{n}$. Think about it, you are just as likely to pick the right key up on the 50th try as you are on the 1st try. Sure, if there are 50 keys in total you are more likely to have picked it up _before_ the 50th try but it is not more likely that it is on the 1st try specifically. Then it's equally likely. Just like the 11th, 43rd and k:th. This is what is called a uniform distribution. If you look at your own answer for the 2nd try, this actually equals $\frac{1}{n}$